# Excel - concatenating multiple rows into multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

The starting data set is the standard output generated from an online application that cannot be altered.

Date, Qty, Item, First Name, Last Name, Email, Comment, Timestamp, Phone, PhoneType

So if the same person orders 2 items (there are only 2 items available for people to choose from), it creates 2 rows, each with duplicate data other than the item and the quantity.

The output data set is desired to be on a new worksheet and sorted by last name, then first name.

Last Name, First Name, Email, Phone, Item 1 Qty, Item 2 Qty

Here is a file with sample input and output data. Sorry, can't post images until reputation >= 10.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ig3jdd9n7p2h9w/Example.xlsx

Any help is greatly appreciated, Excel is not my forte!

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what didn't work when you tried? It also may be beneficial if you could post a small example of starting data and a desired output, rather than asking people to download and open a file from the intrawebz.

Comment: Dan, I did the work by manual manipulation, but it is not practical for hundreds of rows of data i will have.  i did try to add images of the two tables in excel, unfortunately you cannot post images until your reputation score is 10 or above.  Thank you for the good comment, not sure how to address the issue you noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way should be a PIVOT table ...

[image]

Settings in Pivot Table Tools / Design

- Subtotals: Do not show subtotals
- Report Layout: Show in tabular form (to get names/1st names in seperate fields)
- Report Layout: Repeat All Label Items (for displaying the 2nd Mr. Jones)

Settings in Pivot Table Tools / Options   (if you want ... I did it but it's not strictly necessary)

- Options / Display / Classic Pivot Table Layout

Comment: Mike, thank you for the advice, when I copy what you have done in Excel 2010, I do not get the name Jones in column A for the row that contains Tom Jones data, that cell is blank!  I noticed in your screenshot that you do have Jones in the last name, but it does not have a plus sign in front, how did you accomplish this?

Comment: MikeD - try as I might, I cannot find the following option "Report Layout: Repeat All Label Items (for displaying the 2nd Mr. Jones)"   My report layout drop down allows the selection of compact form, outline form, or tabular form.  No other options?

Comment: in my Excel 2010 the Report Layout dropdown icon is the 3rd icon from the left in icon group "Layout" (leftmost) in the colorized "Design" menu under "Pivot Table Tools"

Comment: Turns out the "Repeat All Label items" option did not exist in Excel 2007.....   time to upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a pivot table with Last Name, First Name, Email and Phone in the Row Fields, Item as a Column Field, and Qty as a Data field.